# AWS Cognito - Login with Facebook on Browser (Not Mobile APP)

Tags: amazon-cognito-facebook

We are attempting to implement AWS Cognito instead of Facebook's Login SDK.

The components are

```
1. Home page acme.com login
1.1 Has Login with FB button
2. Destination page: acme.com profile
```

**scenario A;**  NO Acme session
a1. User is logged in to Facebook in a browser tab;  i.e FB session created and active
a2. Assume User has linked FB id to Acme's FB Login App

```
a3. User opens new tab acme.com login 
a4. Clicks login with FB > 
a5. FB login window pops up - [see][1]
a6. User's Login session via Acme's FB App ID  is created
a7. user is redirected to Home page
```

**Scenario B:**
User closes Acme.com tab (does not log out) and reopens new Acme.com tab
**Expected behaviour**

```
b1. Page loads
b2. User's FB Session (Via Acme's FB Login App ) is recognized
b3. User is logged into Acme and navigates to home page
```

Problem
We are noticing that in Scenario B
The user is not automatically redirected from b1 to b3

The user is required to click on login with FB page to proceed.

Any working examples?

Reference [site expedia](http://www.expedia.com) :  . try logging with FB, and closing tab (do no logout of Expedia, browser and opening a new browser session and reloading expedia.com